# Possible to change Windows 8 "Hot Corners"

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to customize what actions are performed when you mouse into the hot corners in Windows 8?

Comment: AFAIK no. Although you can dock apps to the sides or alternatively use Alt+Tab to navigate between programs the usual way.

Comment: My guess for their reasoning, is to maintain at least some consistency.

Comment: I would agree but you can customize Apple's hot corners

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can change their actions, but you can disable them by editing the registry/using Skip Metro Suite (http://winaero.com/download.php?view.33).

source: http://www.instantfundas.com/2012/08/disable-start-screen-and-hot-corners-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes !! you can.

1st you should disable default hot corners in Windows 8. download this script and run it
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmz5ckztbzrsm95/disable-win8-hot-corners.reg

2nd install a small 3rd party app (free App), this will enable you to customize hot corners
https://sites.google.com/site/programsforpeers/hotcorners