# Disable Windows 8 Charms Bar top-right reveal corner

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to change Windows 8 “Hot Corners”](https://superuser.com/questions/494179/possible-to-change-windows-8-hot-corners)

Is it possible to set the reveal mode of Windows 8 Charms Bar to show **only** after pointing the mouse at the *bottom-right* screen corner - thus *disable* the *top-right* reveal corner?

It is very annoying that the Charms Bar always shows when I am closing maximized applications.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, what you can do is disable the mouse shortcut all together and use Win+C to show the Charms bar when you need it.